# Translate data in view sent from controller

Tags: zend-framework, view, controller, translate

I have a question about translating data sent from the controller to the view.
I can translate text in my view like this `<?php echo $this->translate("Hello World!"); ?>`

But in my controller I have this:

```
$this->view->message = 'Welcome! You do not have any surveys or quizzes yet.
                                To start creating your first survey or quiz,
                                click the button "Create New Survey" or "Create New Quiz".';
```

And in my view:

```
<?php echo $this->message ?>
```

How can I now make sure that the message will be translated? (I work with gettext and .po files ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `$this->view->message = 'yourstring'` in your controller, use this:

```
$this->view->message =  $this->view->translate('your string to be translated');
```

Comment: *Best practice*:
Translation is part of the presentation layer. So you should translate everything in your views not in your controllers.
Controller :: `$this->view->message = 'your string to be translated';`.
View :: `echo $this->translate($this->message);`